# Восклицательный знак внутри скобок

Tags: пунктуация

Возможна ли постановка восклицательного знака внутри предложения?

Например:

> Там было древо познания — и насаждённое в начале не
>   злонамеренно, и запрещённое не по зависти (да не отверзают при сем уст
>   богоборцы, и да не подражают змию!): напротив того, оно было хорошо
>   для употребляющих благовременно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри скобок может ставиться **вопросительный или восклицательный знак**:

Между тем лесок, который я недавно проехал (какой там лесок — осиновые кустики!)...начал смутно проступать (Сол.).

Быть может (лестная надежда!), укажет будущий невежда на мой прославленный портрет… (П.);

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128